# Load image to framework

Tags: swift

Good day,

I've been working with my custom framework in Swift. I'd like to add an image to my framework, but it doesn't have the `Assets.xcassets` folder to load the image.

Does anybody know how to do this?

Comment: Have you tried adding an Asset catalog to your custom Framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Xcode choose File > New File > Asset Catalog. The dialog looks like this:

[image]